# Is LIMIT not allow in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query

```
  SELECT employeedept, execoffice_status, employee, COUNT(*) AS 'employeetotal', YEAR_cse1 =YEAR(execoffice_date)
FROM CSEReduxResponses
WHERE execoffice_status = 1
GROUP BY employeedept, execoffice_status, YEAR(execoffice_date), employee 
order by [YEAR_cse1],
LIMIT 20
```

Which when I add the LIMIT it gives me a error "Incorrect syntax near '20'.". 
Is there another way to get the top 20?

I have 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.0.2531.0, SQL server 2008.

Comment: Maybe I'm gonna get my first flag, but this took approximately 5 seconds to find the answer by searching "sql server limit"

Comment: don't get a flag... give one for "duplicate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably looking for `top`

```
SELECT TOP 20 employeedept, execoffice_status, employee,
COUNT(*) AS 'employeetotal',YEAR_cse1 =YEAR(execoffice_date)
FROM CSEReduxResponses
WHERE execoffice_status = 1
GROUP BY employeedept, execoffice_status, YEAR(execoffice_date), employee 
order by [YEAR_cse1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the documentation for `select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx), you'll see that it uses the keyword `top`, [whose documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) says that it

> Limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number of rows or
>   percentage of rows in SQL Server 2012. When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY
>   clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it
>   returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order. Use this clause to specify the
>   number of rows returned from a SELECT statement or affected by an INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE,
>   or DELETE statement.

So you can get what you want by saying something like

```
select top 20
       *
from foo
```